# Find the probability of getting 20 heads in 40 flips of a fair coin

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

> Find the probability of getting $20$ heads in $40$ flips of a fair coin

I did this problem with the binomial distribution and got my probability as $0.12537$.

However, I am being asked to do this using normal approximation to the binomial distribution with continuity correction.

So i'm using the formula:

$$ Z=\frac{x-np}{\sqrt{npq}}$$

where $x=20,n=40,p=\frac{1}{2},q=\frac{1}{2}$

I have:

$$P(x=20)=P(19.5<x<20.5)=P(\frac{-.5}{\sqrt{10}} < Z <\frac{.5}{\sqrt{10}}) $$

However, I'm not sure what to do after that. This is the first time I worked with a normal approximation case that involves exactly, it usually involves less than or greater than.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Your last expression, which is correct, involves inequalities and is handled in the familiar way.

Comment: Note that the last equality is only approximate, $\approx$ rather than $=$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, so good.

Once you have got the limits for z, proceed as usual, look up a z-table.

Comment: so will i have two probability values?

Comment: There are two equal probabilities on either side of the mean which need to be added up. How exactly you arrive at the answer will depend on the type of z-table you use.

Answer (score 1):

Formally your approach is correct.

However, I would rather use the [*local* limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem):
$$
P(X = 20) \approx \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi npq}}\,e^{-\frac{(20 -np)^2}{2npq}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{20\pi}}\approx 0.1261.
$$
This gives a worse approximation that the one you wrote (which gives about $0.1257$), but it does not use any special functions.